# SQL Server - Create a custom auto-increment field

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to produce a custom auto-increment functionality in sql. my custom auto-incerement ID should be like below...

```
S1501.001
```

"S" is for Supplier's name first letter.

"15" is for this year's last 2 digits.

"01" is today's month

"." will always be there

"001" is my incrementer.

the counter will go on like below

```
S1501.001
S1501.002
S1501.003
S1501.004
```

Firstly, I have to find the "S1501." and find the ID with highest digits at the end. I can create a new "S1501.005". How can I do this?

I have done something but didnt work.

```
SELECT TOP 1 (SELECT SUBSTRING('S1501.001', 7,3)),* 
FROM LG_001_01_SERILOTN 
WHERE  CODE LIKE SUBSTRING('S1501.001', 1,6)+'%'
ORDER BY (SELECT SUBSTRING('S1501.001', 7,3)) DESC
```

Comment: Why do you need to store this as a combined value? What happens when you delete S1501.002, do you change the values of 003 -> 002 and 004 -> 003?

Comment: What happens when 2 supplier's names start with the same letter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CompanyID AS 'S1501.' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblCompany` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCompany(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CompanyID` will contain values like `S1501.001`, `S1501.002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.