# Custom autogenerated ID in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a custom auto-generated ID in this format:

```
yyyymmdd-xxxxx
```

where:

- `yyyymmdd` is the present date and
- `xxxxx` is an auto increment integer number starting from 0

and the next day xxxxx should be restarted to 0.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another column which stores the auto increment integer

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27845180/864696

Comment: Look into using a `Sequence`, if you need `xxxxx` to start over with each new date.

Comment: no, but if you have a solution based on other auto increment column I can add it.

Comment: @RossPresser That version restart counter on next day?

Comment: yes, it restarts in the next day.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you can put anything in your computed column, including `CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)` Because the computed column is `PERSISTED`, it will be computed upon insert and never changed after that.

Comment: This question is still a duplicate and should be marked such for future reference. The other question has a good answer and should be considered authoritative.

Comment: @pepe, I dont see where that will reset the ID counter.... this will create sequence .... `day1.01 ... day1.02.... day2.03....day2.04 ....etc`

Comment: But @marc_s answer that question and edit this one, No one better than him to say if those are duplicated

Comment: @RossPresser: unfortunately, since it's dealing with date arithmetic, the formula becomes **nondeterministic** and thus **cannot** be persisted...

Comment: @marc_s you're right.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you are also right: no reset per day. I missed that requirement of the OP.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using?? In SQL Server **2012** and newer, we now have a `SEQUENCE` datatype, which would be ideal for this - you could easily reset this every night to get a fresh round of numbers every day

Comment: I would recommend you NOT do this. You are violating 1NF with this. You are shoving two distinct values into a single tuple. You are putting too much importance on values that shouldn't have any real significance.

Comment: What is your purpose for a column like this?

Comment: customer requierement.

Answer (score 1):

- Create one autonumeric `ID` column in your db
- save the date/time of each insert row.

Then use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function

```
SELECT *,
       dayField + '-' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM (
        SELECT  ID, dateTimeField,
                -- truncate the time and convert to yyyymmdd
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast(dateField As Date), 112) as dayField,        
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY cast(dateField As Date)
                                   ORDER BY dateTimeField) as rn
                                  -- or just ORDER BY ID
     ) T
```

Now if you want save this on the db, you probably will need a trigger.

Comment: Note this generate consecutive numbers, for example if you want use it for a report. But if you want use it as FK. You **CANT** use it because will break with any delete.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider including an Identity column and a datetime column that will be set on insert and than add a calculated column to put the two together.