# I want to generate new id based on previous id in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one table which will be stored qno as 'res/12-19/001'.

I want to Increment it by 1 but when I increment it by 1 the new qno will be res/12-19/2.

I want it to be res/12-19/002.

I am using following statements in sql stored procedure:-

```
Select top (1) @OriginalQNo=QNO from Quo order by QNO desc

SET @NewQNo=RIGHT(@OriginalQNo, 3) + 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Create a custom auto-increment field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845180/sql-server-create-a-custom-auto-increment-field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Why convert `@OriginalQNo` to a `varchar` and then to an `int`? What you're describing seems to be a `SEQUENCE`, as your above SQL will give you numbers 0-999.

Comment: *"I have one table which will be stored qno as 'res/12-19/001'."* That's the source of your problems. Seems like you are cramping up multiple data points into a single column, which is never a good idea to begin with. You should use separate columns to store separate data points. If you need this format for display, it's as easy as `select col1 + '/' + col2 +'/'+ col3 from...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem as described in your question, consider the following:

```
DECLARE @NewQNo         VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @OriginalQNo    VARCHAR(20)
SET @OriginalQNo = 'res/12-19/001'

SET @NewQNo = RIGHT('00' + CAST(RIGHT(@OriginalQNo, 3) + 1 AS VARCHAR), 3)
SET @NewQNo = LEFT(@OriginalQNo, LEN(@OriginalQNo) - 3) + @NewQNo

PRINT @NewQNo
```

In order to format the number as a 3-digit one with trailing zeroes, you simply prepend two zeros as a string to the start of the number and then extract the right-most three digits, which will produce in this case `002`.

In order to also include the rest of the question syntax, the second `SET` line prepends the starting characters of the question (in this case, `res/12-19/` to the completed 3-digit string.

Output:

```
res/12-19/002
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are using SQL Server 2017

Try this:

```
DECLARE @OriginalQNo VARCHAR(MAX) = 'res/12-19/001';

SELECT STRING_AGG(K.NewValue, '/')
FROM
(
    SELECT K.value,
           K.RN,
           CASE RN
               WHEN 3 THEN
                   RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST(K.value + 1 AS VARCHAR(3)), 3)
               ELSE
                   K.value
           END AS NewValue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT value,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@OriginalQNo, '/')
    ) AS K
) AS K;
```

Read more about [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [REPLICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)